# Trying to add keyboard events to a child movieclip I call to the stage in code

Tags: actionscript-3

So this is my first semester in school coding and right now I'm trying to make a little 2D game with a character who I need to move up and down.

So far, I've been able to create a titlescreen and then when you click start it goes to the next screen, where my main character is.

I add him to the stage manually through the code, and then I tried to make him move up down left and right with the arrow keys but he only appears, and does not move.

This is my code so far

```
package lib.fly 
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;


    public class FlyGame extends MovieClip
    {

        public var mainCharacter:MovieClip;

        public var vx:Number;
        public var vy:Number;





            public function FlyGame()
                {


                    trace ("Initiate");
                    init();

                }

            private function init():void
                {
                    vx = 0;
                    vy = 0; 

                 addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

                 stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, moveAround);    
                 stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, dontMove);

                  //var dx:Number = speed* Math.cos(angle);
                  //var dy:Number = speed* Math.sin(angle);

                    trace ("Keyboard Event Listeners");

                }


            private function moveAround(event:KeyboardEvent):void
                {
                    trace ("Actual Keyboard Events");

                    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
                    {
                        vx = -5;
                    }
                    else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
                    {
                        vx = 5;
                    }
                    else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
                    {
                        vy = - 5;
                    }
                    else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
                    {
                        vy = 5;
                    }
                }

            private function dontMove(event:KeyboardEvent):void
                {
                    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT || event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
                    {
                        vx = 0;
                    }                   
                    else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP || event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
                    {
                        vy = 0;
                    }

                }

            public function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
                {
                    mainCharacter = new BoyFlying();
                    mainCharacter.x = 20;
                    mainCharacter.y = 150;

                    mainCharacter.x += vx;
                    mainCharacter.y += vy;

                    addChild(mainCharacter);

                }   
    }

}
```

The output produces the trace statements up until my "Actual Keyboard Events"

Sorry, I'm brand new to this so any help would be appreciated. Thank you for your time

Comment: You're re-creating your character in `onEnterFrame` in every frame at the same coordinates so it never moves away from there. You need to create your movieclip instance once and just access it later.

Comment: That makes sense... so I moved it to the public function flyGame but I seem to run into the same problem where my character appears but it still does not move and there are no errors coming up but it still doesn't output the actual keyboard events trace I have under the moveAround private function

Answer (score 0):

Try this logic below and see if it helps your program to work as expected...

Adjust function `init()`

```
private function init():void
{
    vx = vy = 0; //chain them since same value

    mainCharacter = new BoyFlying(); //create once here and control in other functions
    mainCharacter.x = 20;
    mainCharacter.y = 150;

    mainCharacter.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
    addChild(mainCharacter);

    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, moveAround);    
    //stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, dontMove); //what is it good for?

    trace ("added... Keyboard Event Listeners");

    //var dx:Number = speed* Math.cos(angle);
    //var dy:Number = speed* Math.sin(angle);

}
```

Adjust function `moveAround()`

```
private function moveAround(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    trace ("Actual Keyboard Events");

    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) 
    { vx -= 5; }

    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
    { vx += 5; }

    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
    { vy -= 5; }

    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
    { vy += 5; }
}
```

Adjust function `onEnterFrame()`

```
public function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
{
    //# no need for += here since function moveAround() changes these vx and vy values on key press
    //# infact your character could be moved (x/y) just by keyboard event instead of per FPS screen update (eg: not with EnterFrame)

    mainCharacter.x = vx;
    mainCharacter.y = vy;

}
```